# R.raw is (broken)... I cannot reference anything with it. Android 2.2

Tags: android, eclipse

When I try to make a reference to any file in //res/raw/ Through the R class, it acts as though I do not have the 'raw' directory in the project. I checked in the project files as well as in the eclipse IDE - it is definitely there.
here:

`MediaPlayer mp = MediaPlayer.create(Project.this, R.raw.Gunshot);`

This code prevents me from compiling... Eclipse says "raw cannot be resolved or is not a field.

I have restarted, refreshed, and built the project without that code, but it will not go away.
HELP

Comment: According to your last comment, every reference to `R` is considered an error. But it's a common problem: [R cannot be resolved](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5780990/1267661)

Comment: Here's a [better description](http://stackoverflow.com/q/885009/1267661).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I figured it out. I was looking the logger and did not see in the console that filenames in the 'raw' folder have to be lowercase. I think it also does not build the 'raw' object until there are files inside it. It thus appeared to never generate the object. Thanks guys.

Answer (score 4):

Find "`import android.R`" and delete them. Then `Clean` your project and `Build` it.

This would be the most common problem in Eclipse Android.

Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/885009/r-cannot-be-resolved-android-error) out, this you can find many solutions here.

Answer (score 0):

how about Project>clean and rebuild the project?

Comment: Well something happened at least. I cleaned, and then it gave me the same error, except now it couldn't find "R"!

Comment: I then imported it, and now it is giving me trouble with the actual resources, but now it is doing it everywhere, not just in the "raw" file.

Comment: is there any error generating R at console? If res folder has error, it fails to generate R class

Answer (score 0):

On Android Studio 4.0 after:

- Clean&Rebuild
- Rename raw file to lowercase a-z, 0-9 and an underline

Reference resolved only after **Invalidate Caches and Restart** AS.