# R cannot be resolved to a variable even i have build and clear project

Tags: android, android-layout

Hello every body i have been facing this problem from several days ,i have searched it every where but no result.i have clear and build project but still error " R cannot be resolved to a variable" and also i don't found R.java in project folders.

Comment: check if there is any error in xml resources.. or in any other place.. check the console for eror

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/5780894/1838457

Comment: i have checked there is nothing like that,becoz this error comes in all java files of my projects

Comment: there is an error like this:2013-05-27 11:02:14 - prefrences] Unable to resolve target 'android-10'
[2013-05-27 11:02:14 - prefrences] Unable to resolve target 'android-10'
[2013-05-27 11:02:14 - practice] Unable to resolve target 'android-13'
[2013-05-27 11:02:14 - LearningInfoTech] Unable to resolve target 'android-16'

Comment: check package name in manifest file is same as in ur java file.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16636039/java-lang-classnotfoundexception-after-changing-nothing-in-the-project-but-upgra/16636127#16636127. try this if you have updated adt to rev 22

Comment: ya dear i have updated my adt to rev 22.the error comes just after updation

Comment: Hi @SajadBinNazir Update your sdk

Comment: @SajadBinNazir then follow the link i posted in the above comment. That should solve your problem. Make sure you have installed the build tools from the android sdk manager

Comment: ok then again click on update sdk and install build tools

Comment: @SajadBinNazir which will you give Android SDK "Build tools", it is required for  22.0.0 adt version.

Comment: Recheck your imports , and make sure you don't have any import that ends with .R; , also try to recheck resources for any capital letter named picture or xml .

Comment: i am not able to open even my sdk manager,it shows check for updates and finaly ends with no update found @Raghunandan

Comment: @SajadBinNazir i can't help coz i am not aware of it. May be other can.

Comment: ok @Raghunandan no problem thnks for ur suggestion

Comment: I also want to add that R.java is missing in generated java files

Answer (score 0):

If you're running a 64-bit system, you need to install ia32-libs:

```
 sudo apt-get install ia32-libs
```

Answer (score 0):

R.java  is java generated file .so you can't change details on R.java file. If your faceing problem for that. please check xml file for activity and add resouecres. R.java file will bepalced in "Gen " folder in your project files.