# How to resolve Android R import, file not generated

Tags: java, android, eclipse

I am learning android using eclipse. I created my first project.
**package- com.example.testmobileapp

Min Target Ver - 3.x

Max Target - 5.1** 

 I tried to as much as information I can gather from already asked question but unable to sort this out so finally asking here.
I included **android-support-v7-appcompat.jar** to resolve error and used **AppCompatActivity** to extend in my mainActivity class. 
 And as  so many question already been asked to resolve the **import android.R;** I tried the following ways

1. Removed the import android.R statement(which resolved some error) but R cannot be resolved to a type still lingers as it is referenced.
2. Deleted BuildConfig.java in gen folder,Clean & Build the project as mentioned at so many places to generate R.java @ this place.<>
3. Closed and restarted eclipse(No use)
4. I am getting error in **values/styles.xml**,(please check image reference for error), I tried to correct it using this [Can't Find Theme.AppCompat.Light for New Android ActionBar Support](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17870881/cant-find-theme-appcompat-light-for-new-android-actionbar-support), but no luck!

Tried Urls
 1. [R cannot be resolved - Android, no import android.R; statement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5780822/r-cannot-be-resolved-android-no-import-android-r-statement)
 2. [import android.R in Eclipse : Why?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15309941/import-android-r-in-eclipse-why)
 3. [Developing for Android in Eclipse: R.java not regenerating](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2757107/developing-for-android-in-eclipse-r-java-not-generating) 

Please find the image reference.[image: WorkSpace 1]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: You posted everything, but the error. Which is the most important thing.

Comment: @DerGolem Please check the 4 point in which i mentioned styles.xml and uploaded the image also, Can't make it more clearer than that!

Comment: Of course, you can. Simply `copy-paste` the **FULL error TEXT**, not a cut over image!

Comment: I mentioned everything ,as most of the stack overflow community asks what u tried, so i posted what i tried, n where I am stuck

Comment: I can only read: **/home/jaggi/workspace/TestMobileApp/res/values-v14/styles.xml:8: error: Error**. Which is **not the error text** I need to see.

Comment: @DerGolem I think u understood the problem, can u please tell me wht i hv to chnge

Comment: No. I didn't. I see **no error description**. I can only see the file **where** it happens, but not **why** it happens.

Comment: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name '@style/
 Theme.AppCompat.Light'.   Getting this in styles.xml

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21059612/no-resource-found-that-matches-the-given-name-style-theme-appcompat-light

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I am getting error in values/styles.xml,(please check image reference
>   for error), I tried to correct it using this Can't Find
>   Theme.AppCompat.Light for New Android ActionBar Support, but no luck!

This is your problem. Errors in your application's XML files prevent `R` from being generated.

After your `styles.xml` is without errors, the problem should be fixed.

**Edit:**
Make sure you are using the right library project as described in the accepted answer of [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22271759/fixing-error-in-styles-xml-to-generate-r-java-no-resource-found-name-theme-ap).

Comment: I am so glad u answer in this way!! Boss exactly every single person answering the same damn thing without actually telling HOW TO RESOLVE IT, THAT'S My Problem

Comment: Try to use the AppCompat  Library. That is why it is unable to find the Theme.

Comment: @Abhishek Please refer the 3rd image's 3 import statement, is that what u referring or something else?

Comment: @NarendraJaggi No man you have to include the library like the way in the below answer. Once you include that library in the project, it will compile definitely. If it still fails then please let me know.

Comment: @Abhishek I should follow the TimoSta answer?

Comment: @NarendraJaggi You can follow his answer too. Both points to to the same approach. I hope your problem is solved. :)

Answer (score 0):

I have faced the same issue, it happens automatically sometimes. I don't know the reason. But I got rid of the solution by this. Just try to clean the project, In the Menubar, you have Build, under that there is Clean Project, run that once.

Comment: thanks for attempting the answer,Did u even read the ways i tried before posting the questions, please read the question properly.

Comment: Oops! My mistake, have faced the same issue, so did a bit of hurry to answer.